# Unzipping a file in R Shiny using unzip() fails when deployed

Tags: r, shiny, unzip

I'd like to unzip a compressed .mdb file in the `www` folder of my shiny app, query it for data, and then remove it. `Unzip()` works on my local machine, but when I deploy the app at shinyapps.io, it has issues unzipping the file. Because I'm not able to `read.table()` the resulting file (it's an .mdb) I don't think `unz()` will work.

This code works when run on my local machine

Server:

```
require(shiny)    

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

   observeEvent(input$run,{ #Run Button

     dbName=unzip('www/test.zip', list=T)
     output$name=renderText({
        paste(dbName[1])
     })

     db=unzip('www/ttt.zip', exdir='www', unzip=getOption("unzip"))
     test1=read.csv(db) #.csv for simplicity, but my problem uses a .mdb
     file.remove(db)

     output$testcount=renderText({
        paste(sum(test1))
     })

  })#/Run Button  
})#/SS
```

ui:

```
shinyUI(
  sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(width=3,

           h5('ZIP test'),                                           
           p(align="left", 
              shiny::actionButton("run", label = "Run!")
           ),                                           
           textOutput(outputId = "name"),
           textOutput(outputId = "testcount")                                           
      ),

      mainPanel(width=9,
           plotOutput(outputId = "probs",height = "550px")
      )                              
  )
)
```

But fails when uploaded to Shinyapps.io.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong here?  I've tried passing the file path directly, and messing with the `unzip=` options, but to no avail. If I remove the second call, It will tell me the name just fine, but if I try to unzip the file, it breaks.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT

I was able to get it to work by removing `exdir='www', unzip=getOption("unzip")` and just looking for the file in the root directory: `test1=read.csv('file1.csv')`

Comment: This does work for me, can you post some example zip files?

Comment: I'v never used shinyapps.io but if you have command line access you could try checking the file permission for the zip files (and changing them with chmod 755 myzip.zip). Also I had to remove the `unzip=getOption("unzip")` part from your unzip call since this gives and error message about windows specific options (try removing this if shinyapps runs on linux).

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I was able to get it to work by removing the code you suggested, and unzipping it to the root directory (as @Sebastian   mentioned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using unzip() on shiny-server and everytime the function is called the content of the .zip is saved in the root directory of the app. I asume thats a problem for shinyapps.io.

In the documentation you can only specify the location where the file is with 'exdir' from what I read.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Unzipping to the root directory worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just import the zip library

library(zip)

And use 'zip::zip' instead of zip when you are using zip.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).