# shiny - “The application failed to start: exited normally with code 137, signal 9 (SIGKILL)”

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Hello.

I was working on a shiny application and all was well until I added another visualization from the same data I have been using since I started running the App. At the time, the data was less than 1.5gb, yet the app worked fine locally for the first few graphs.

I did not receive any errors when running the app locally, but when I tried to publish it gives me the error: “The application failed to start: exited normally with code 137, signal 9 (SIGKILL)”.

I looked into this and [it mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67574252/shiny-with-paid-plan-error-the-application-failed-to-start-exited-normally) not having enough memory on shiny, to which the free subscription has a limit of 1gb. So I cut my data down to less than 0.8gb and I commented out everything I had on the shiny except for this bit of code:

```
library(DT)
library(TTR)
library(dplyr)
library(derivmkts)
library(fresh)
library(highcharter)
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(vroom)

tickers = vroom("tickers.csv",delim=",",col_types=cols()) 
termdf = vroom("termdf.csv",delim=",",col_types=cols())

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

ui <- {dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title=""),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(pickerInput(inputId="name",label="",choices=tickers,options=list('live-search'=T,size=6),width="100%"),
                               menuItem("Dashboard",tabName="db"),
                               menuItem("Relative Value",tabName="rv"),
                               menuItem("Earnings",tabName="er"),
                               menuItem("Calculator",tabName="calc"))),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(tabItem(tabName="db",
                     fluidRow(box(status="primary",DT::dataTableOutput("scan1"),width=12,collapsible=T)),
                     fluidRow(
                       tabBox(
                         tabPanel("Price Chart",highchartOutput("pxchart"))),
                       tabBox(
                         tabPanel("Volatility",highchartOutput("volchart")),
                         tabPanel("Skew",highchartOutput("skewchart")),
                         tabPanel("Contango",highchartOutput("conchart")))),
                     fluidRow(tabBox(tabPanel("Volatility Cone",highchartOutput("volcone"))),
                              tabBox(tabPanel("Option Volume",highchartOutput("ovchart")))),
                     fluidRow(tabBox(tabPanel("Skew Structure",highchartOutput("skewchart")),width=4),
                              tabBox(tabPanel("Term Structure",highchartOutput("termstr")),width=4),
                              tabBox(tabPanel("IV30 Spot Correlation",highchartOutput("ivpxchart")),width=4))))))
}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

server <- function(input, output) {
  t0 = reactive({
    x = input$name
    x
  })
  output$pxchart = renderHighchart({
    t1 = t0()
    x1 = termdf %>% filter(ticker==t1)
    x2 = xts::xts(x1$priorCls,ymd(x1$tradeDate))
    
    highchart(type="stock") %>%
      hc_add_series(x2,type="line",name="Close Price") %>%
      hc_legend(enabled=T) %>%
      hc_rangeSelector(selected = 4) %>% 
      hc_add_theme(hc_theme_flatdark())
  })
}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am only trying to load the price chart output in this bit of code locally, but even that isn't loading. As far as I know, I am under the instance size... what's happening/how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and give a reproducible example when you're looking for help with something like this. The example you've given isn't reproducible because it uses local csv files.

Looks like you've got two outputs with the same id `"skewchart"`. Two outputs with the same ID isn't allowed and will cause your UI to fail because it will generate invalid HTML.